# Nodejs Express Return Error Code with Res.Render

Tags: node.js, express, http-error

I am using nodejs with express. I would like to return a custom 404 not found error page. I have it working. however I have not found a solution of how to return a error code with res.render(). I saw a few similar questions but they were old and using deprecated methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

check these:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404);
    url = req.url;
    res.render('404.jade', {title: '404: File Not Found', url: url });
});

      // Handle 500
app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500);
    url = req.url;
    res.render('500.jade', {title:'500: Internal Server Error', error: error, url: url});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I cannot find confirmation in Express docs but using:

`res.status(statusCode).render(page)`

Status and render the page correctly.

```
express: "4.17.1"
```